# Some of the encoding of hyphen(-) showing the result â€“ and some are showing correct on same page(DB used is Sql server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters, meta-tags

I have 2 servers :-

server 1 - shows the correct result for the hyphen(-)

server 2 - showing â€“ character for some hyphen(-) only

I am using the meta tag with charset UTF-8

All the values are coming from my SQL server 2008 Database and DB is good regarding the character hyphen(-)

On IE its showing the correct character but issue is on Chrome and Fire fox

Whats wrong I cant find it out

Comment: That hyphen is likely an en-dash (–) or other "non-standard" hyphen. In other words, a non-ASCII character. That means you need to handle encodings correctly to handle non-ASCII characters correctly. See the duplicate. There's more to it than just an HTML meta tag.

Comment: @deceze I am using Sql server 2008 and it uses the character set ios_1 by default and I am using UTF-8 in html page. Do you think this can be the issue?

Comment: Write/search for a question specifically for doing this with SQL Server, I don't know.

Comment: @deceze I have edited the question and mentioned.

Comment: See if the HTTP content type response header has utf-8 set as charset, I've had issue where the meta charset was set but was ignored and setting the HTTP header solved it.